# Does $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ with those operations constitute a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

If given set $V = \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ and field $\mathcal{F} = \mathbb{C}$ with operations defined for all $\vec{x}, \vec{y} \in V, \vec{x} = x \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}, \vec{y} = y \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ as:
$$\vec{x} \oplus \vec{y} = x\cdot y$$
$$\alpha \odot \vec{x} = \alpha\cdot x$$
Is it really enough to take $\alpha = 0$, which gives $\alpha\cdot \vec{x} \notin V$ to prove that this is not a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$? I.e. just one counterexample is enough, right?

Comment: Since $\alpha\odot x$ is not defined for $\alpha=0$, the problem doesn't even start up. Note, to the contrary, that $\mathbb{R}_+$ (the positive reals) is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ with $x\oplus y=xy$ and $\alpha\odot x=x^\alpha$. This cannot be done over the complex numbers, because complex exponentiation cannot be defined as a single-valued operation.

Comment: @egreg so this is a correct disproof? :-)

Comment: In my opinion there is nothing to disprove.

Comment: @egreg: I don't really understand your comment. $\alpha\odot x$ is defined to be $0$. As the OP points out, this is not in $V$, so $\{V,\mathcal F,\oplus,\odot\}$ is not a vector space. What's wrong with this?

Comment: @TonyK Since $0\notin V$, there is no definition.

Comment: @egreg: It certainly defines _something_ -- it's just that the something it defines does not have the properties that the term "vector space" requires it to have.

Comment: @HenningMakholm In order a set $V$ is an $F$-vector space there *must* exist a function $F\times V\to V$ to begin with. Here there's none.

Comment: @egreg: That is an argumen that the thing being defined here is not a vector space -- nobody disputes that. But just because the thing being defined is not a vector space doesn't mean that the definition of the-thing-that-happens-not-to-be-a-vector-space is not there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that is enough to show that the definition doesn't work.

$\odot$ is supposed to be $\mathcal F\times V\to V$, but the definition shown here produces values outside $V$ for at least one combination of $a\in\mathcal F$ and $\vec x\in V$. This is enough to disqualify the purported thing from being a vector space.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. The set $\mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\}$ with usual multiplication is an abelian group, so $V$ with $\oplus$ is an abelian group. The problems arise with "scalar multiplication", and although one example is enough, it's also true that distributive laws fail for (almost) any $\alpha,x,y$

$$\alpha\odot (x\oplus y) \neq \alpha \odot x \oplus \alpha\odot y$$